# Ellipsoid coordinates, basic integration

Tags: integration

I would like to calculate the volume of an ellipsoid. Let $a > b > c$, and use the coordinates on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoidal_coordinates#Basic_formulae).

$x^2= \frac{(a^2 + \lambda)(a^2+\mu)(a^2+\nu)}{(a^2-b^2)(a^2-c^2)}$

$y^2= \frac{(b^2 + \lambda)(b^2+\mu)(b^2+\nu)}{(b^2-a^2)(b^2-c^2)}$

$z^2= \frac{(c^2 + \lambda)(c^2+\mu)(c^2+\nu)}{(c^2-b^2)(c^2-a^2)}$

$J = \frac{(\lambda -\mu ) (\lambda -\nu ) (\mu -\nu )}{\left(a^2-b^2\right) \left(a^2-c^2\right) \left(b^2-c^2\right)}$

So I would take the Jacobi $J$ as the volume element under the integral, but what about the parameters $\lambda,\mu, \nu$? What values do they take to describe the whole volume?

Are there any easier alternative coordinates that I could use to parametrize an ellipsoid?

EDIT:

I also need the Laplace operator in ellipsoid coordinates.

Comment: You can use the fact that the are of the ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ is $\pi ab$. Find the area of ellipses in terms of distance from the origin on any axis and then integrate that with the suitable limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an aligned ellipsoid at the origin, you can parameterize it in polar coords:

$$
x = ar \sin t \sin p \\
y = br \cos t \sin p \\
z = cr \cos p
$$
The substitution 
$$
x = arX\\
y = brY \\
z = crZ
$$
then turns your integral into $abcr^3$ times the volume of a unit sphere, so your answer is 
$$
abcr^3\frac{4\pi}{3}.
$$

Comment: I tried deriving the Laplace operator with your coordinates, but I get something too complex.

Comment: I have no idea what this means. In what way is the Laplace operator relevant here?

Comment: Ah... I see. You added that part of the question more than *two weeks* after I answered the question you originally asked. Someone else might be willing to help you if you showed what work you've done so far on the Laplace part of the question.